# Getting circular dependency warning upon formulating username creation

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, countif

So I am trying to create a sheet to help our HR Department create the emails for new hires. One of the issues is we use a format of First Initial Last Name as our naming scheme, but if you don't check it can double up with common last names. HR usually does not check for previous emails that currently exist.

Basic recreation I am trying to do is this:
[image: Sample Table]

Username: `IFS(F2<>"", F2, IF(COUNTIF(A:A, D) > 1, E2, D2)`

First Choice: `LEFT(B2, 1) & B3`

Second Choice: `B2 & B3`

What I want for A2:
So basically if Override is set, i want it to use that. If no override is set, i want to check and see if First Choice is already found in column A, if it is already used then use Second Choice. I keep getting a circular dependency. I even tried having the calculation done in Column G, which works. But once I try and set A2 to G2, it gives the circular dependency error again.

Comment: Could you share a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, along with the outcome you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can outsmart it...

paste in **A2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(F2:F<>"", F2:F, 
  IF(COUNTIFS(IF(F2:F<>"", F2:F, D2:D), 
              IF(F2:F<>"", F2:F, D2:D), ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))=1, 
              IF(F2:F<>"", F2:F, D2:D), E2:E)))
```

[image: 0]

paste in **D2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LOWER(LEFT(B2:B, 1)&C2:C))
```

paste in **E2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LOWER(B2:B&C2:C))
```

Comment: This is looking great! thanks so much. I am going try testing it with more data now. Then try and make sense of what is going on within your formula.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting  a circular dependency you may just need to change the calculation settings.

Go to File > Spreadsheet Settings > Calculation and switch Iterative Calculation on

Let me know if this doesn't work!

Comment: I saw that in the suggestion of the error, so i tried it. I did and it did kinda work, but not reliably. I forgot what the result was, but it was still getting confused.